# How to find "if not null" using switch statement

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement. I'm wondering how to make a case of "If not null". I'm pretty sure this is valid, but i'm not finding anything on the interwebz about it.

```
// Switch on Count
switch($this->_count) {
    case !"":
        return true;
    break;
    default: 
        return false;
    break;
}
```

So writing `case !"":` means when `$this->_count` is not null return true, otherwise return false. Can't i do this with one of those weird looking if statements? The one written with a "?" and a ":"? I haven't used those much. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I should think you just have to do `return !empty($this->_count);`

Comment: *"Can't i do this with one of those weird looking if statements? The one written with a "?" and a ":"?"* - FYI: It's called a ternary operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to over engineer these things, just use simple IF statements:

```
if(is_null($this->_count)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Or super simply:

```
return !is_null($this->_count);
```

Just for your information though, you CAN use switch to evaluate expressions like this:

```
switch(true) {
    case is_null($this->_count):
        return true; //dont need break; since return ends execution
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Does using case `case !"":` work as well? Or is it better to use the is_null() function?

Comment: Well `""` is an empty string, I don't see how it helps with testing is something is null...and `!""` evaluates to true in PHP (for various reasons). Basically that `case` you have currently is `if($this->_count === true)`, which by no means is testing if something is null or not.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I'll be marking your answer as the correct one! :P I'm just super tired and clearly not thinking. Thanks again!